# For Skobbler maps iOS SDK, how to control when app asks for location permissions?

Tags: ios, skmaps

When we enable offline skobbler maps, as soon as the user loads the map, it asks for the location permissions. We have built our own 'current location' button and would like for the app to ask for permission only when the user presses the current location button. I was told that this functionality would be included in the latest version of skobbler but couldn't find any documentation/examples. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I'm using a [CLLocationManager](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html) that [start to update location](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CLLocationManager/startUpdatingLocation) once the view is loaded, the permission is asked automatically. Then I save a flag (already located) also you can store a user Default with that flag.